# Question on the USB connector shileding

Tags: capacitor, usb, esd, shielding

I have a USB microphone, based on cm6533 chip, that appears to be in working condition, with the exception of it's fried USB type C connector. Upon closer inspection this is the circuit that houses the connector itself: [image: type_C_PCB] I am bewildered by the components that are in close proximity, those are: what appears to be 4 capacitors(2 more on the other side), 1 transformer and 3 mysterious SMD components with "AC" marking on top.

**Questions are:**

1. What are those necessary components that require such a close proximity to the connector? And how may I research more on this topic, countless different "silly" queries didn't yield much.
2. Will it be detrimental for the device if I just cut up a spare USB cable and solder V+ D+ D- and GND to the pads on this PCB?

P.S.: My best guess is that those capacitors are used for "noise cancellation" in the cable, but other components leave me guessing.
P.P.S.: I have searched for type C connector variant and found it, but waiting 4 week for the delivery is beyond my patience.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Standard interface components on USB interfaces to block electromagnetic interference from coming in or going out of the connector, and electrostatic discharge protection. There are protection (ESD) diodes for USB data lines and VBUS, common mode choke for USB differential data pair, and bypass capacitors for VBUS supply voltage.
2. Detrimental? Depends. It might work just fine, but the bypass caps and ESD proection will not be in-line on the wiring, and it would bypass the CM choke. It would likely work, but be slightly more susceptible or generate more electromagnetic interference. Unlikely that you will see any difference.